# How can determinant of an MVD be a super key in a relation in 4th normal form?

Tags: database, database-normalization, functional-dependencies, unique-key

Many books on RDBMS define a relation schema R(X,Y,Z) to be in 4th normal form, if for every non-trivial MVD X ->> Y,  X is a super key.  However, I fail to understand how the determiner X can be said to be a super key when we say it multi-determines Y, which implies Y may have multiple values for a given value of X. A super key is expected to uniquely identify dependent attribute values. So, how can X be a super key in the relation schema R where Y may have multiple values for the same value of X in the instances of R? The books I referred to give examples of only trivial MVDs.

Comment: Re most clearly phrasing what your post is trying to ask, see the version I just edited & will roll back. Re what it is trying to ask, we are more or less back to my 1st & 2nd comments, with the problematic/erroneous claim being that "Y may have multiple values for a given value of X" contradicts "[X] is expected to uniquely identify dependent attribute values". "What is your justification for it?" OK, it "may have multiple values". That doesn't imply it has to. What is the problem?

Comment: Alas you replaced "can" by "may" but they are more or less synonyms without the context saying precisely how they are used & are similarly ambiguous about what cases can arise when. One can't reason clearly under those conditions. Precise natural language requires echoing the form of predicate calculus. Over all cases of some MVD X->>Y holding in some relation, in some cases X has multiple Ys, OK. But that doesn't exclude some case of some MVD X->>Y holding in some relation where X has only 1 Y. (The latter is when both X->>Y & X->Y, ie when X->Y.)

Comment: (X,Y,Z) shouldn't appear where it does & is another example of getting the scope and or quantification wrong when using implicit quantifications.